# How to put message to IBM MQ version 8 using console (LINUX)?

Tags: ibm-mq

Currently evaluating IBM MQ version 8, and trying to put message using console. I understand that in version 7.5 there is this command called [amqsput](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q004410_.htm#q004410_) & [amqsget](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q004420_.htm#q004420_), however I can't found this command in version 8. Is there any equivalent command in version 8? Or do I need to use the MQExplorer for this?

Comment: I believe this [link](https://geekflare.com/amqsput-command-not-find-ibm-mq-on-linux/) may help you

Comment: @siarheib Oh. I didn't install the sample rpm. Can you put your comment to an answer? I will accept your command there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many sample programs provided by IBM for this purpose.  To obtain them for Linux, install the MQSeriesSamples RPM as described in [*Installing IBM MQ server on Linux*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q008640_.htm).

After installation, the `amqsput` command will be available in `/opt/mqm/samp/bin` if the default install location is used.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Answers that are just links are discouraged on SO.  In particular, please see [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) which advises "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." Also, links to official docs are preferred over 3rd party sites when possible.  I have updated the answer with a better description and pointed to IBM's docs.  Feel free to continue to improve it as you always have edit privileges on your own content.

Comment: amqsput only pushes messages upto 100 bytes. If message is bigger than 100 bytes then command breaks it up and creates small messages upto 100 bytes each until the entire message is processed.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-q-qload

Here are forks of useful MQ utilities Q and QLOAD (MA01 and MO03), they are unfortunately no longer supported by IBM.
The project is ready to build for most platforms.

Comment: QLOAD was integrated into the product at V8 - it's now called dmpmqmsg

Comment: Note: `dmpmqmsg` can only use structured `qload` files, not plain text messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with JMS messages (and not "plain" MQ messages), you can use a tool like [JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/) on sourceforge to post/browse/get etc messages